# Azure Data Factory SFTP Source Please check if the path exists. If the path you configured does not start

Tags: azure-data-factory

Hi I'm getting the following error....

GET METADATA works fine if I do WildCard like *ASN* to find list of files when I do for loop and pass each file name in the COPY Activity (Source)

ErrorCode=SftpPathNotFound,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Can't find SFTP path '/Receive/INX_XXXXXXXX_ASN_20210728012200817116546932367669276.xml'. Please check if the path exists. If the path you configured does not start with '/', note it is a relative path under the given user's default folder ''.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.SftpConnector,''Type=Renci.SshNet.Common.SftpPathNotFoundException,Message=/opt/apps/uprd1bpn1/bpfs2/2021/July/0209/04/22/25565817aec33de9cnode2_WF128489406.dat (No such file or directory),Source=Renci.SshNet,'

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like there are two different paths being referenced, one to an xml file and one to a .dat file. If you just did a straight lookup with hardcoding the path, are you able to view the file you want?

Comment: Nope.Hardcoding just one file also fails. Like I mentioned the MetaData works fine. Only Copy Activity fails. I changed the Max Concurrent Connections to 1.

Comment: I know I have ran into this before. Have you used a application like WINSCP to connect to the FTP with the same account and copy the file yourself?

Comment: Yes, it works fine. We copied the files to local FTP server in our Dev environment and I used the same pipeline it works fine. No Errors.

Comment: Can you attach screenshots of how your lookup and your copy activity Source are configured? you can blur sensitive stuff, I just want to see if you are using dataset parameters or wildcard paths, etc unfortunately it is possible the FTP server is incompatible with certain functions, but a straight copy activity shouldn't be one of them

Comment: Are you using a Self Hosted IR or AutoResolve IR for connecting? It's possible you could be running into some IP issues. I know there was a FTP server that I could connect to successfully and even do a Metadata activity, but then I couldn't copy from until they whitelisted IP range. (we actually set a static public IP on our VM so they whitelisted just that one IP for our self hosted IR... otherwise there are 4000 IP's whitelisted because of the IP pool that Microsoft has for autoresolve compute)

Comment: Using the AutoResolveIntegration Run Time. Will try whitelisting and see .....

Comment: You will have to whitelist all of the IP ranges in your ADF region. Here is the link to get the IP ranges https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519

Comment: There are number of possible reasons for this error. Can you please share the ADF JSON ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue described above, the only difference was the type of my source file, `.txt`.
In my case the error message was misleading, the actual error message was getting hidden by the 'chunking' option. If you pay attention to the source tab of the copy activity, by default it is set to use 'chunking', which transfers your data at an increased speed.
By disabling chunking, I could notice the error was actually in a particular line of the file, then fixing the file, fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.**  Check if **"Copy behavior"** on the sink side is marked as **"None"**.

**2.**  Check if you have **permissions for uploading the files**.

**3.**  For wildcardFileName Dynamic content of fileName should be replaced with `asterisk (*)`.
E.g. If `20210728012200817116546932367669276` is dynamic content in your filename
then `wildcardFileName` for `INX_XXXXXXXX_ASN_20210728012200817116546932367669276.xml` should be `INX_XXXXXXXX_ASN_*.xml`

Refer - [SFTP as sink - getting can't find SFTP path error](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5aafb0e2-443b-4c27-a426-5f53e11aa07b/sftp-as-sink-getting-cant-find-sftp-path-error?forum=AzureDataFactory)